# Set Extended Styles on Win32 Edit Control

Tags: c++, c, winapi, editcontrol

Is it possible to set extended styles on Edit control (simple Edit, not Rich Edit)? For example, I want to set the extended style to `WS_EX_ZOOMABLE | WS_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL`. The creation of the control is as follows:

```
HWND hEdit = CreateWindowExW(
        ES_EX_ZOOMABLE | ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL,
        L"EDIT",
        L"",
        WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        0, 0, 100, 100,
        hWndMain, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hInstance, NULL
    );
```

The problem is that none of the extended styles work. The `EOL` is still `CR LF` and the control isn't zoomable.

Comment: I think you're meant to set these styles by sending the control an [`EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setextendedstyle) message.  You're getting confused with _window_ extended styles.

Comment: That's it but I don't know what wParam and lParam should contain.

Comment: @IvanVenkov That why there is documentation usually easily accessible by pressing **F1** in Visual Studio or by doing a search on Google. If the later one does not give expected result, add some of these keywords like: **msdn, C++ win32 api** or similar.

Comment: @Phil1970 There's documentation behind that link!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in comments, edit control extended styles are set by sending the control an [`EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setextendedstyle) message:

```
HWND hEdit = ::CreateWindow(
        L"EDIT",
        L"",
        WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
        0, 0, 100, 100,
        hWndMain, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hInstance, NULL
    );

DWORD exStyles = ES_EX_ZOOMABLE | ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL;
::SendMessage( hEdit, EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, exStyles, exStyles );
```

You pass the style bits you want to **modify** as the `wParam` argument (the *mask*) and you pass the **new values** of these bits as the `lParam` argument. This allows you to both set and clear styles using a single call, without having to query for the previous values of these styles. This is a very common pattern used by many APIs.

If you **only want to enable** these styles, set `wParam` and `lParam` to the **same values**, as I did in the code sample above.

If you want to clear style bits, leave out the ones you want to clear from the `lParam` argument. E. g. to set `ES_EX_ZOOMABLE` but clear `ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL`:

```
::SendMessage( hEdit, EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, ES_EX_ZOOMABLE | ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL, ES_EX_ZOOMABLE );
```

To clear both bits:

```
::SendMessage( hEdit, EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, ES_EX_ZOOMABLE | ES_EX_ALLOWEOL_ALL, 0 );
```

---

**Manifest requirements**

For the extended styles to actually work, you need to [specify **version 6.0** of the common controls in the application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview#using-manifests-or-directives-to-ensure-that-visual-styles-can-be-applied-to-applications). One of the easiest ways to do this is to insert the following compiler directive in your code, typically in the precompiled header file:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

---

**Background information**

This is likely how the control handles `EM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE` in terms of **bit-wise operations**:

```
auto newExStyle = currentExStyle & ~wParam | lParam;
```

- Invert all bits of `wParam`, using bit-wise NOT (`~`).
- Apply the result as a mask to `currentExStyle`, using bitwise AND (`&`). This clears all these bits from `currentExStyle` that were initially set for `wParam`.
- Using bit-wise OR (`|`), set the bits that were passed for `lParam`.

Comment: zett42 to the rescue :)